# Should cognitive science questions be asked here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm looking mainly at [Human perception of time depending on age](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/623/389). It's a very cog sci question that doesn't really related to the underlying biology but the explanations may involve it. Does it belong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you been over to [cogsci.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com) yet?  I don't think anyone would mind me pointing it out, as there are no doubt others like me that would like to see both sites thrive.  This very issue has been [discussed](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119/splitting-up-questions-on-neurobiology-between-cognitivesciences-se-and-biology) on their meta as well.

Since everyone is still in Beta, it's a good time to determine the division of labor between the two for topics like neuroscience/cognitive science, so that there's cross-fertilization rather than competition.

If it's exclusively a biology question, it's probably better off staying here, obviously, but if there's some ambiguity, ask on the metas to gauge appropriateness like you would for any other SE site.

Comment: Didn't even think of looking up cogsci.SE or looking up the previous question about this topic: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/129/389

Comment: @bobthejoe Forgot about that one, I think I've read them all I just didn't remember which question was asked on which meta.

Comment: @bobthejoe The other thing too, is that we can migrate between the two sites (which shouldn't be a substitute for doing "homework" using meta posts, of course), so that leaves some options open for moving a question that is not getting love on one site or the other.